# Call to action! We need more moderator nominations!

Tags: discussion, election

The nomination phase of our moderator elections ended on Monday 21st. August 2017 at 20:00 UTC.

Note that Stack Exchange has a rule that there must be **at least one more candidate than positions available** (so there genuinely is an election).

When the nomination period finished we had 3 nominations for 3 positions, and therefore the election could not proceed (the 3 nominated people were **not** automatically elected).

---

*Update*

The nomination period was **extended by 7 days** to give other people a chance to nominate. It will now close at 20:00 UTC on Monday 28th. August 2017.

---

If you are one of the many users who post frequently, help clear the review queue, and have an interest in this site, please [nominate as a moderator candidate](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/election). Who knows? You might be elected! You would join a small, friendly team of moderators who keep an eye on moderator flags. Moderators have their own chat room for private discussions. There is also a Stack Exchange chat room for *moderators only* from all sites, where issues can be discussed and resolved.

Moderation is not particularly onerous, unlike the higher-activity sites like Stack Overflow. You may only have to look at a few flags each day.

---

At the time of editing (Wednesday 23rd. August) we now have 4 nominations, however it would still be helpful to have more nominations. Nominating shows an interest in the site, and gives voters a wider range of choice when voting.

Comment: Beside Nick, I want to see Edgar Bonet, Code Gorilla or Majenko as moderators. I think they have the technical and personal skills for the job.

Comment: Was queuing up an announcement to discuss that we are, indeed, extending the election, but I think I'll just piggyback off of this as an official announcement: due to insufficient moderator count, **the nomination period of the election has been extended by an extra 7 days**.

Comment: I would be a terrible moderator. The delete button would be abused.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, moderator actions are extensively logged. They don't have *carte blanche* to do whatever they like. :)